# Import CSV in Postgres with static data in other columns

Tags: postgresql, bulk-insert

How can I [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) a CSV file in Postgres along with static data for the columns not in the CSV? In MySQL I can do `LOAD DATA INFILE ...` and profile the column names along with any values for the columns not present in the file. I want to do something similar with Postgres but this is not supported by the `COPY` command.

Answer (score 6):

You will have to create an intermediate table as the target of `COPY`, and then insert into the final table in the second step.

If you don't have to keep the intermediate table (for cross-checking your results, or as an easy retry point), you can make it temporary and unlogged:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TEMP UNLOGGED TABLE intermediate (... columns matching the CSV contents ...);

COPY intermediate FROM 'your.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv, ...);

INSERT INTO final_table (column1, column2, column_with_default1)
SELECT col1, col2, 'default'
  FROM intermediate;

-- check if everything looks fine, row counts match the expectation, etc.

COMMIT;
```

[`UNLOGGED`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtable.html#AEN78527) will prevent a lot of WAL writes when the CSV is big.  I put the defaults into the `SELECT` part of the `INSERT` instead of the (temp) table to save resources - there is no need to store the same default values many times.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL isn't an ETL tool. You should do your ETL with other tools.

If you want to add a column to a CSV, just do something like this:

```
awk '{print $0, "static value"}' OFS=, my.csv
```